# Git production release

Tags: git, cgi-bin

I've setup Git to manage our code. Say server 'live-server' is our production server with 'project.git' as a bare repository. Everyone pushes to that 'project.git' and when all the testing is done - what is the proper way to move from project.git to web root directory on our live-server? I saw examples using hooks - are there any better alternatives? Is there any standard?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: you mean release management, just try git archive -o /tmp/latest.zip v1.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard, but a `post-update` hook which:

- `cd` into the destination ("prod" or "live") directory
- `git pull` from the bare repo (`project.git`)is enough

Make sure to specify the `--git-dir` parameter though in your hook, or the git pull will fail.
See "[Git - post-receive hook with git pull “Failed to find a valid git directory”](https://serverfault.com/questions/107608/git-post-receive-hook-with-git-pull-failed-to-find-a-valid-git-directory)" for the details.

```
cd /path/to/live
git --git-dir /path/to/project.git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change your web-root to 'project.git'?

I found some [instructions](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.txt) on how to publish a git repository over HTTP.